# Converting to different timezones

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to show the user Datetime based on their timezone, I want to post the timezone selected by the user and get the converted times, I have multiple Datetime objects, so need to convert them all.

for example I have this date in UTC 
2018-08-24 18:00:00+00:00 and I have a function that converts it to the user timezone, how can we go about running that method and returning the serialized data back to the user,

```
class TimeSlots(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    time_slots = models.DateTimeField() #utc time here 


class SlotsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   


    class Meta:
        model = TimeSlots
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to you, do converting datetime in frontend, not backeend.

for example, if your frontend is angular, you can send UTC datetime to angular and now convert UTC to local datetime:

```
<p>{{ myUTCDatetime | date:'MM/dd/yyy - HH:mm' }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, it does make sense to convert time zones in the fronted !

Answer (score 0):

Use **`default_timezone`** parameter of **`DateTimeField`** as,

```
import pytz

my_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')


class SlotsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    time_slots = serializers.DateTimeField(default_timezone=my_tz)

    class Meta:
        model = TimeSlots
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here I converted the **`UTC`** time to **`IST`**

Comment: it does make sense, but how can I convert from UTC to X, and X being a user input of a timezone lets say IST selected on the front-end ?

Comment: Somehow you need to pass it as argument to the view, and then to the serializer